# Understanding fmt (gnu coreutils)

Tags: shell, coreutils

I'm using fmt (GNU coreutils) 8.25 and I fail to understand how to use it.
In particular, I don't understand the following results.

1. `$ echo -n "a b c d e" | fmt -w3 -g3`

   I expected to obtain

   ```
   a b
   c d
   e
   ```

   but I get

   ```
   a 
   b
   c 
   d
   e
   ```

   So I thought maybe `fmt` counts the linebreak it inserts and tried
2. `$ echo -n "a b c d e" | fmt -w4 -g4`

   But then, I get:

   ```
   a
   b c
   d e
   ```

   Finally, I don't get the following:
3. `$ echo -n "a b c d e" | fmt -w4 -g1`
   which I expected to give

   ```
   a 
   b
   c 
   d
   e
   ```

   but instead again results in

   ```
   a
   b c
   d e
   ```

So, obviously I'm failing to understand how the `-w` and `-g` options work.
Could someone please explain the output of my three examples?

Comment: Once we get a better idea of what's going on, please edit the title to make it more useful for future use.

Comment: I can answer only the second part. `fmt` tries to avoid line breaks before the last word of a sentence (as per `info fmt`). So it tries to avoid `e` alone on the last line.

Comment: If `fmt` is meant for re-flowing plain text, single-character words and such a low number of columns probably aren't something it's really meant for... If that's what you actually want to work with, there might be better tools

Comment: @janos, but that sounds like an answer to the question as stated...

Comment: I want to clarify: In some text, that I generated with fmt, I had a strange looking output and thought that maybe I misunderstood how to use fmt. So I played around with the parameters and ended up with the above "minimal examples".
I think my intuition that "narrowing down the maneuvering space" for fmt will produce a "less heuristic" result lead to a question that maybe has no useful answer.(1/2)

Comment: (2/2) After janos' comment (thanks!) I think that probably I just (once again) underestimated the subtle rules in typesetting (in corner cases).
I agree with ilkkachu that probably fmt isn't the right tool for the test cases in my "minimal examples".
So probably I _did_ understand how to use fmt and my initial problem wasn't a technical one but a question in the typesetting domain.

Answer (score 0):

It won't answer your question about coreutils' `fmt`, but you can solve your string manipulation cases with `sed` as well:

```
printf "a b c d e\n" | sed 's/.\{1\} .\{1\} /&\n/g'
```

result:

```
a b 
c d 
e
```

`.\{1\}` corresponds to a single character.

Answer (score 0):

The intended result can be obtained also with xargs, as in:

```
printf "a b c d e\n" | xargs -n2 -d" "
```

producing

```
a b
c d
e
```

And not just for single characters:

```
printf "one two three four five\n" | xargs -n2 -d" "
```

producing:

```
one two
three four
five
```

Best wishes ... cheers, drl